# Large number of DNS queries

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So there was a situation on our campus network with a computer talking to a networked ROS core that generated 9,172,713 DNS queries over a few hours.  The machine that issued the requests was NOT the roscore.  Is this normal or is something likely configured incorrectly?

I've only run on private wifi routers, so I've never had IT report extreme DNS usage. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9768/large-number-of-dns-queries/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-19**:
Sure sounds like a lot. I just ran rviz on my desktop (connected to my robot's machine which ran roscore and most of the nodes), and it executed < 1 query a minute (which could have well been other stuff on the machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's unusual, but without more details about what was running on the computer, it's not easy to understand the problem.  DNS queries should only result when:

- a node initializes
- a service call is issued

Also, monitoring scripts, like rxgraph, will do much more frequent queries as they do not maintain persistent connections to the nodes they are monitoring.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-04-20**:
Yes, regardless of DNS query issues, a service call at 100Hz should use a persistent connection instead.  That is really high rate for a service call.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-20**:
Looks like the problem was a service call (calling a forward kinematics solver) at 100Hz. Assuming the server doesn't change, using a http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Services#Persistent_Connections should reduce the number of DNS queries, right?